# Return multiple objects from an apply function in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm practicing with using `apply` with Pandas dataframes.

So I have cooked up a simple dataframe with dates, and values:

```
dates = pd.date_range('2013',periods=10)
values = list(np.arange(1,11,1))
DF = DataFrame({'date':dates, 'value':values})
```

I have a second dataframe, which is made up of 3 rows of the original dataframe:

```
DFa = DF.iloc[[1,2,4]]
```

So, I'd like to use the 2nd dataframe, `DFa`, and get the dates from each row (using apply), and then find and sum up any dates in the original dataframe, that came earlier:

```
def foo(DFa, DF=DF):
    cutoff_date = DFa['date']
    ans=DF[DF['date'] < cutoff_date]

DFa.apply(foo, axis=1)
```

Things work fine. My question is, since I've created 3 `ans`, how do I access these values?

Obviously I'm new to `apply` and I'm eager to get away from loops. I just don't understand how to return values from apply.

Comment: I don't think apply is best option for this. If I understand correctly why not DFa[DF.index].sum()?

Comment: I agree, it's a pretty lousy example. My main problem is trying to return from the apply. I would really like to see how I could return 3 different dataframes, and sum them up elsewhere (but I didn't mention that in the question appropriately).

Comment: That's okay, it's possible that groupby might be a better alternative to look into. You can specify groups for the 3 subsets then simply use the sum method on the resulting groupby object.

Comment: @MattO'Brien: The performance of DF.apply(func, axis=1) is comparable to calling func in a loop. apply is useful when you want to align the output into a single DataFrame. If you need to return 3 disparate DataFrames, go ahead and loop over DF.iterrows(). For better performance you'll have to think of a better way to calculate the result (such as doing a sorted cumsum for the toy example above) or perhaps use Cython.

Comment: wow @unutbu you just laid it down right there, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your function needs to return a value. E.g.,

```
def foo(df1, df2):
    cutoff_date = df1.date
    ans = df2[df2.date < cutoff_date].value.sum()
    return ans


DFa.apply(lambda x: foo(x, DF), axis=1)
```

Also, note that `apply` returns a `DataFrame`. So your current function would return a `DataFrame` for each row in `DFa`, so you would end up with a `DataFrame` of `DataFrames`

Comment: So hypothetically, what if I actually wanted to return a dataframe of dataframes? `DF_of_DFs = DFa.apply(lambda x: foo(x, DF), axis=1)` doesn't seem to be appropriate...

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit of a mixup the way you're using `apply`. With `axis=1`, `foo` will be applied to each *row* (see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)), and yet your code implies (by the parameter name) that its first parameter is a DataFrame.

Additionally, you state that you want to sum up the original DataFrame's values for those less than the date. So `foo` needs to do this, and return the values.

So the code needs to look something like this:

```
def foo(row, DF=DF):
    cutoff_date = row['date']
    return DF[DF['date'] < cutoff_date].value.sum()
```

Once you make the changes, as `foo` returns a scalar, then `apply` will return a series:

```
>> DFa.apply(foo, axis=1)
1     1
2     3
4    10
dtype: int64
```